# Behavior seems to indicate SQL Server is taking a long time to do an insert

Tags: sql, sql-server

In my application I am writing log messages to a table in SQL Server (2012 Express or 2014 Express).

I am seeing behavior that looks like the inserts are taking a long time to actually happen (the application does something that should generate a log message, but the log message does not show up until seconds or minutes later)

Is that possible? Are there settings or something I can set to change this?

I am generating the SQL statements with C# in case that's relevant.

Comment: It might help to share your table structure, data, and code.

Comment: You should also include what is this behaviour, since we can't know what you see on the screen.

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to ask kind of a higher level question.  One specific example is creating a simple record (single row insert) through C# asp.net webpage and the web page has completely finished and returned it's response, but the insert does not show up in management studio when querying for SELECT * FROM mytable - but later it does show up.  Seems like something - SQL Server, IIS, .Net - is holding onto the insert... maybe the table was locked?  I don't know enough about SQL Server to guess.  What I'm asking for are some educated guesses.

Comment: It could be dirty reads. What happens if you run your mgmt studio query with tablock? Does it return straight away? If not you might have a clustered index getting rebuilt with possible page splits under the hood. SQL will do this kind of index reorganise after it returns success so a nolock query (or read uncommitted) could in they miss the inserted row.

Comment: It could a lot of things. The table being locked is a definite possibility and from the behavior described this is very likely. It could be a number of other possibilities though.

Comment: @johnMcTighe how would dirty reads delay the results? If it were dirty reads it would be the other way around. :)

Comment: @sean lange- imagine this scenario. Select with nolock starts. Clustered index gets rebuilt. Row gets moved Behind select scan. Select misses row. Possibly that's a dirty write as opposed to a dirty read but you can see how the select query could miss the inserted row.

Comment: Hey aerik. Is there any way you might be querying a replica database? Is there SQL replication or SQL always on involved?

Comment: Oh I see what you are saying now. I wasn't understanding what you meant about dirty reads there. I wasn't thinking dirty reads here because the OP stated they tried to query it in SSMS and it wasn't there. If it was because of a dirty read it would have a super small window where it could missed.

Comment: And I sure hope they aren't using NOLOCK for writes as that can corrupt indexes.

Comment: Nope, no possibility of querying a replica, and I'm not using NOLOCK for anything.  But I do have a lot of other queries running against that database and possibly even that table.  Sounds like maybe I need to go educate myself about table locks.

Comment: You could use SQL Profiler to observe when the statement is run and when it's finished. If you're doing some kind of asynchronous write in your app, that would explain why the app returns but the record doesn't appear for a while